# How to set username/password mosquitto?

Tags: passwords, mosquitto

I used the `mosquitto_passwd` command to create a password file.

```
mosquitto_passwd /etc/mosquitto/passwd admin
```

I added the path to my password file in `mosquitto.conf`:

```
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
```

But when i subscribe or publish it doesn't require username/password?

```
mosquitto_sub  -t '#' -d
Client mosqsub/19032-Dell sending CONNECT
Client mosqsub/19032-Dell received CONNACK
Client mosqsub/19032-Dell sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: #, QoS: 0)
Client mosqsub/19032-Dell received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

By default, Mosquitto will still allow anonymous connections, i.e. connections where no username/password is provided.
In addition to the `password_file` entry, you also need:

```
allow_anonymous false
```

Comment: @datnq almost 2 years later, don't forget to accept :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything that was needed for me to get it working was already on this page, but scattered, so below are the complete required lines to add to the mosquitto_conf file:

```
listener 1883
password_file /etc/mosquitto/password_file
allow_anonymous false
```

Answer (score 0):

`password_file` MUST not be empty. Or password is not required.